# How can I make GNU screen run a command or script every time I create a new window?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

I'm trying to write a script that makes [GNU screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) call virtualenvwrapper's `workon` command to jump to an existing virtualenv based on the screen session name.

I've managed to make it work when the session starts, but I want to be able to run commands everytime a window is created, and I can't find hooks or anything similar to it.

Does screen allow a way to run commands everytime a window is created within a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the logic into your `~/.profile` (if using the `deflogin on` setting) or `~/.mkshrc` (or similar, depending on your shell) file. Something like this:

```
if test -n "$STY"; then
        # we are inside GNU screen
        screenpid=${STY%%.*}
        screenname=${STY#*.}
        # do your magic
fi
```

In this scenario, `$screenname` will contain either the name passed to the `-S` option of GNU screen, or something like `ttyp0.shorthostname` or `pts-9.shorthostname` (depending on the OS) if `-S` was not used.

Comment: Awesome, that should do it, I'll try it out (I use zsh, so that'll go into my .zshrc). Thanks a bunch!